# Angular 7 Wait for http network call to finish before triggering next one

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I have a data service that triggers http calls periodically and when required by other services. Now, this services work asynchronously so it may happen that the data service is requested to trigger an http call while a previous one hasn't yet finished.

I was wondering how I could use rxjs to check if there's an undergoing call when I need to make an http call

Data Service:

```
constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

// if this gets called while another hasn't returned, wait for it and then trigger the next http call
public request(method, url, options): Observable<any>{
    return this.http.request(method, url, options);
}
```

Service A:

```
public syncA(){
    setTimeout(() => {
       this.dataService.request('GET', 'someUrl', someOptions).subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('periodic call returns ', response});
    }, 45000);
}
```

Service B:

```
public doB(): Observable<any>{
 return this.dataService.request('GET', 'someUrl', someOptions)
}
```

The situation would be when service B invokes doB while syncA has triggered a request and hasn't yet finished.

Comment: The obvious answer is to make the second request use from the first request's `subscribe` callback. Is that not workable for your use case?

Comment: @TheHeadRush can you provide a sample on how this will be? The sample is simplified, in the actual application they may be several services that trigger https calls at different moments, some every certain amount of time, some others explicitly by the user's decision

Comment: Indeed, A and B are just interested on the calls they make, they don't need to know other stuff undergoing over the data service, this one should handle the requests along they come waiting for one to finish before triggering the next one... If they listen to all responses they would be receiving information that they are not interested about when other stuff is finished from other services

Answer (score 3):

The rxjs way of doing this would be using **concatMapTo**

- [learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmapto.html](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmapto.html)

As the [stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-fkkh6c?file=index.ts&devtoolsheight=50) shows

```
const fakeRequest = of('Network request complete').pipe(delay(3000));
//wait for first to complete before next is subscribed
const example = sampleInterval.pipe(concatMapTo(fakeRequest));
//result
//output: Network request complete...3s...Network request complete'
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a behaviourSubject to store a loading prop and release the pipe only when it's false, something like this:

```
private loading = new BehaviouSubject<boolean>(false);

constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

// if this gets called while another hasn't returned, wait for it and then trigger the next http call
public request(method, url, options): Observable<any>{
    return this.loading.pipe(
        filter(value => value === false),
        take(1),
        tap(() => this.loading.next(true)),
        mergeMap(() => this.http.request(method, url, options)),
        tap(() => this.loading.next(false))
    );
}
```

Comment: this almost seems the way to do it, though I can still see that on some cases multiple requests are invoked without waiting for the previous that is running to finish. consider the case where I have for instance a service that calls 

public doInServiceC(){ return forkJoin([ this.ds.request(m1,u1,o1), this.ds.request(m2,u2,o2), this.ds.request(m3,u3,o3), ... ]).map(() => { return })}

if this is the case I see that with the solution all these requests get invoked altogether

Comment: So you need some of the requests to wait all be finished and others to be able to request anytime?

Comment: I would need each request to wait for the previous one to finish, doesn't matter if its 1 that comes while another is being called or 20 that come at the same time and should queue for then being called one at a time until no one is left... if in the meanwhile of clearing this queue of request to make, more come along they should queue as well

Comment: Maybe instead of using a boolean type variable to store loading, you could store a integer that counts for each request you made and when it gets the result, it will decrement the counter...I'll try to update this code by tomorrow.

Comment: uhmm... thinking more about it, maybe a simple counter won't work. I guess you need something like a queue list to place those requests and continue the pipe  when it gets popped...